# HTTPS и подгрузка картинок по HTTP. Нужен CDN

Tags: https

Есть некий сайт server.com на нем есть https. При этом сайт подгружает картинки с удаленного ресурса any.com. К сожалению, any.com не поддерживает https что приводит к тому, что некоторые браузеры ругаются что мол загружается небезопасный контент.

Первый вариант найти админов any.com и с помощью палки заставить их подключить https - к сожалению отпадает( сервис находится за бугром, а просьбы по почте они не воспринимают.

Одно из решений проблемы - написать скрипт-прокси, и вставлять ссылки вида:

```
https://server.com/proxy.php?http://any.com/image.jpg
```

Но такой вариант не совсем подходит. Переживаю, что сервер быстро загнется - слишком много таких запросов будет приходится на одну страницу. Кешировать это все тоже не реально, не хватит места на жестком (картинок реально очень много 7000 * 20 * 3 = ~420 000 шт., и они частенько обновляются, появляются новые, удаляются старые).

Третий вариант - подключить какой нибудь CDN на который можно будет ставить линки типа:

```
https://cdn.com/?http://any.com/image.jpg
```

Но вот проблема - не знаю похожих сервисов. Подскажите что нибудь?

Comment: [CloudFlare](https://www.cloudflare.com/plans)? Раньше у них https был только в платных планах, теперь пишут вроде, что в бесплатном SSL есть, только что заметил.

Comment: @Sergiks, не CloudFlare не подходит. У них нет такого проксирования как я выше писал. И работают они только через подмену NS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем сам вот нашел два подходящих сервиса с проксированием изображений по HTTPS:

- https://cloudimage.io/ **€4 per month**
- https://embed.ly/ **$9 per month**

Может кому пригодится.

Answer (score 0):

1. Imgix - http://www.imgix.com/ (то что вам нужно, просто придется изменить хост картинок в файлах, допустим с www.ya.ru на yaru.imgix.com)
2. или храните фотографии на Flickr (1TB)

Comment: Flickr под задачу не подходит.

А у imgix цены уж совсем не демократичны, см http://www.imgix.com/pricing минимальный прайс - 50$ в месяц.

Comment: @IntellectSys, да, цены высокие). Кстати, а почему бы вам не создать поддомен, выпустить для него сертификат, и перекинуть все картинки туда?

Comment: @misc я думал над этим, но фотки грузятся с удаленного сервера, контроля над ним у меня нет. И фоток там около 360000, это нереально) плюс они переодически меняются/добавляются/удаляются, т.е. просто один раз их все выкачать к себе - не прокатит.
Это централизованный каталог товаров с API, по API помимо инфы о товаре, отдаются URL-ы картинок каждого товара. Картинки размещены на их сервере. И HTTPS они включать не хотят (точнее не могу достучаться до них).